# How correctly to write RegEx

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have string `$text = " /var/www/images/mobile/test/test/, 1346744549";` and i need to transform it to `$text = " '/var/www/images/mobile/test/test/', '1346744549'";` - add **'** to each "value" in the string. Problems appears with slashes, i don't know how to recognize it. Here is my sample, but it is wrong already...

```
$text = " /var/www/images/mobile/test/test/, 1346744549";
$text = preg_replace("/\b|\/\b/i", '"', $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: maybe `explode(', ',$text)` will help you...

Comment: @k102 with regexp it will be in one step, with explode also need to implode and do othe things.

Comment: @NoNameZ Don't get too hung up on doing it "in one step" (and this is a bit of general advice, not just applied to this problem) - better to do it properly than with less code. Having said that, `explode()` is probably over simplified. How static is the format of the data? Will there always be a leading space before the first data cell? Will their always be two cells, a filename and a timestamp, or could here be other columns? Will the columns always be separated by `,<space>`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the function:

```
"'".implode("','",explode(',',$text))."'";
```

You can see the result here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14ed966d086494933f0e0ff48230083623a9c527

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$text = " /var/www/images/mobile/test/test/, 1346744549";
$text = preg_replace("/[^\s,]+/", "'$0'", $text);
echo $text;
```

The `[^\s,]+` matches any series of non-whitespace, non-comma characters by itself, but with `'` around (the $0 is the match)

If you want **to allow whitespace within the data**, try this

```
$text = " /var/www/images/mobile/test/test/, 1346744549, Hello Foobar test";
$text = preg_replace("/(^\s*|,\s*)([^,]+)/", "$1'$2'", $text);
echo $text;
```

will output

> '/var/www/images/mobile/test/test/', '1346744549', 'Hello Foobar test'

Comment: Assuming that the data can never contain `\s,` is possibly a dangerous assumption.

Comment: @DaveRandom, possible, we don't know. It is the easiest way to exclude the leading whitespace.

Comment: @DaveRandom, I updated my solution to allow whitespace within the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = " /var/www/images/mobile/test/test/, 1346744549";
echo preg_replace('/(?=[,\s]|$|^)/i', '"', $text);
```

Comment: There's a leading space before the first "column" ;-)